# Is it fine to have a .ssh folder inside my webroot?

Tags: security, ssh

I'm curious about this folder that appeared in my webroot named .ssh?

Is it normal or should I delete it?

Comment: 1) A .ssh directory should generally *only* be a home directory; 2) If "webroot" is a home directory then something is already wrong.

Comment: No. unless your doing web-based ssh with your website. Which I doubt since you asked this question

Comment: It's likely that the website is created and maintained by a 3rd party company and was setup the chroot'ed ssh/sftp login on your server. check what you have under that folder.